# Is my C# static method in a non static class thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# class that can be instantiated with different constructors, but it also contains some static helper methods which only work with their parameters and can be called from other classes as well.

Now I wonder whether concurrent calls from different threads to such a method is thread safe or not, or in other words, is it possible that variables inside the static method get changed by call2, while call1 is still in process?

```
public class AwesomeClass
{
  /* constructors and stuff */

  public static bool HelperMethod(object o1)
  {
    string someString = "";
    Func<object, string> doSomething = (o) => { 

        string someOtherString == null;
        if (someString.Length == 0)
        {
          /* time consuming process using o... frequently
             changes someString and someOtherString */
        }
        return someOtherString;
    };
    return doSomething(o1).Length > 0 && someString.Length < 10;
  }
}
```

If `someString` in the example could be changed by a thread2 calling `HelperMethod` while `doSomething` is still working for thread1, I'd be in trouble.

Comment: `someOtherString` is a local variable. There is nothing about thread-safety here to talk about. Another thread would create a new instance of `someOtherString`. So there is actually no shared resources.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating a Func if you don't pass it anywhere?

Comment: It is just an example I made up to illustrate my question... not meant to make much sense.

Comment: Thank you all for explaining this to me and especially for mentioning `o1` as the only possible thread-safety problem. Actually the parameter objects get changed as well, but it is sure that they are always different objects.. no two threads can pass the very same object.

I just marked the first answer as correct, but the others deserve the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your static method does not change any member variables, and does not call mutating methods on its parameters, it is re-entrant, and is, therefore, thread-safe.

Static methods that perform mutating operations on their parameters may not be thread-safe when concurrent threads invoke the method with the same object as its parameter.

For example, if your method mutates `o1` through methods, properties, or public variables, the method would no longer be thread-safe.

Answer (score 4):

`HelperMethod` is thread safe because it does not access any shared data. `someString` is local variable and it will be allocated again every time the method is called.

Note that this answer is not affected by the fact that `someString` is part of the closure. Separate closure object (which contains particular instance of `someString`) will be allocated on stack with every call to the `HelperMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `someString` and `someOtherString` are local to the call, they are not shared between calls. This is just as if had a function call itself, modifying variables in the 2nd call would not modify the first.

The one thing that could be unsafe is `time consuming process using o...`, If the operations you are doing to `o1` are not safe to be done by multiple threads at once you could run into issues.